# passing data from rails controller to AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first example with angularJs and rails 
I am trying to pass data from rails server to angularjs to be displayed in the view 
This haow i proceed:
in my products-controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :json
  def index
   respond_with Product.all
  end
end
```

in layouts.application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sportsStore">
<head>
 <title>Angular</title>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 <script>
   angular.module("sportsStore", []);
 </script>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'controllers/sportsStore.js' %>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">

   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
   </div>

     <%= yield %>

  </body>
  </html>
```

in assets/javascripts/controllers/SportsStore.js

```
angular.module("sportsStore", ["ngRessource"])
.controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $resource) { 

  Datas= $resource("/products") 
   $scope.data= Datas.query() 

});
```

in welcome/index.html.erb

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="item in data ">
<h3>
<strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
 <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
   {{item.price | currency}}
  </span>
 </h3>
 <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
</div>
```

and in routes.rb

```
resources :products, defaults: {format: :json}
root 'welcome#index'
```

but i just got angular binding syntax instead of data

Comment: so any idea for this problem ?